# Сохранение фотографий под разными именами

Tags: java, android, файлы, камера

Как сделать так, чтобы фотографии, полученные с камеры, сохранялись в `/DCIM/Camera/` под именами, получающимися как `image_i`, где `i` - это последовательные натуральные числа (image_1, image_2, image_3 и т. д.).

Вот мой код:

```
int n = 0;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button buttonCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            File imagesFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera/");
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_" + n +".jpg");
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1112);
            if(image.exists()){
            n++;
            image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_" + n + ".jpg");
            cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1112);
          }
        }
    });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

В коде переменная `n` - счетчик. Проблема в том, что при возвращении с активности камеры на главную, счетчик сбрасывается, и новый файл изображения заменяет старый созданный.

Comment: Сам то хоть ответ знаешь?

Comment: Если надо в рамках одного запуска приложения, сделайте `n` статической. Если надо просто формировать файлы в таком формате, в цикле перебирайте `n` и проверяйте, что файла с таким именем не существует. Если надо найти файл с максимальным `n` и создать файл с `n+1` - переберите все файлы с подходящим форматом, найдите максимальный `n` и т.д. Проблема-то в чем?

Comment: Можно записать значение `n` в текстовый файл, а потом читать его. Так как при рестарте приложения значение `n` сбрасывается

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для сохранения фото в названии используется время. По факту оно всегда уникально.

```
String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
 File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_" + currentTime +".jpg");
```

Comment: Если надо именно в формате image_i, где i - это последовательные натуральные числа, то можно тоже использовав время, только не форматированное представление, а как "image_" + System.currentTimeMillis()